# Pass Form dropdown value to controller CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

can i pass form dropdown value in my controller and after this, i can  send the value in my DB table....please help me i m new in cakephp here is my job_content.ctp

```
 echo'<div class="AcceptButtonFormData">'; 
    echo $this->Form->create('Job' ,array('action' => 'view')); 

    $ipr_value=array('0'=>0.0,'1'=>.1,'2'=>.2,'3'=>.3);

    echo $this->Form->input('IPR_teeth_pair12',array('type' => 'select','name'=>'drop12', 'options' => $ipr_value,'default'=>0)); 

    echo $this->Form->input('IPR_teeth_pair23',array('type' => 'select','name'=>'drop23', 'options' => $ipr_value,'default'=>0));

    echo $this->Form->input('IPR_teeth_pair34',array('type' => 'select','name'=>'drop34', 'options' => $ipr_value,'default'=>0)); 

    echo $this->Form->end();
    echo '</div>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can save it. As per above form this will post to you controller action in view

```
public function view() {
    // Has any form data been POSTed?
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // If the form data can be validated and saved...
        if ($this->Job->save($this->request->data)) {
            // Set a session flash message and redirect.
            $this->Session->setFlash('JobSaved!');
            $this->redirect('/jobs');
        }
    }

    // If no form data, find the recipe to be edited
    // and hand it to the view.
    $this->set('jobs', $this->Job->findAll());
}
```

below is just sudo code you can change as per you need and for more understanding you can visit [cakephp.org](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

Comment: thanks for reply.....if i select the drop down value and submit a button dropdown can't save in DB and also if i check the form dropdown value shown 0,means if i select the value i remain selected....

Comment: $ipr_value=array('0'=>'0.0','1'=>'.1','2'=>'.2','3'=>'.3'); use like this may be solve ur issue and print request data in controller